# Find an irreducible faithful FG-module for a given group.

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, representation-theory

I'm looking for an answer to the following question. Any answers or help will be greatly appreciated!

Let G be a group of order $r^3$ with $r$ an odd prime. Assume G is non-abelian and has exponent $r$. Then $G=N:H \cong \mathbb{Z}_{r}^{2}:\mathbb{Z}_{r}$. Let $F=GF(p)$ and assume that $r$ is a divisor of $p-1$. Find a faithful irreducible FG-Module.

Comment: $N:H$ denotes a semidirect product of $N$ by $H$. In general this is ambiguous, as it doesn't specify the action of $H$ on $N$, but here there's only one non-trivial action (up to isomorphism) of $\mathbb{Z}_r$ on $\mathbb{Z}_r^2$. By the way, I'm guessing that by "exponent $p$" you mean "exponent $r$"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its exponent $p$. What is the 'action' of $H$ on $N$, I don't understand?

Comment: A group of order $r^3$ and exponent $p$ makes no sense at all!  You must mean exponent $r$

Comment: Maybe it does mean $r$, but then what is $p$?

Comment: $p$ is any prime such that $r|p-1$.

Comment: OK that makes sense now. Thanks for showing me how to write the question properly! I'm still not sure what it means by $G=N:H$ though?

Comment: @jackwo Irreducible in the sense that it has no nontrivial submodules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I'm basing this on the impression that "irreducible module" is being used in the sense of "having no nontrivial submodules." 
If "irreducible" was not meant in this sense, then please let me know so I can delete.

There are two cases: $r^3$ is coprime to $p$, or it is not.

If $r$ is coprime to $p$, then by Maschke's theorem, $FG$ is a semisimple Artinian ring. If $FG$ had a faithful irreducible module, it would be simple, but if $FG$ is simple, its augmentation ideal is trivial, and $FG\cong F$ and $|G|=1$, so this case is not possible.

On the other hand, if $r^3$ is not coprime to $p$, then $FG$ has a nontrivial Jacobson radical, and no irreducible module is faithful.

This is why seeking faithful irreducible modules among group rings seems doomed to failure. You will only get results with $G=\{1\}$.

Comment: I don't understand. If $r$ is coprime to $p$, then $p$ doesn't divide $r^3$. Thus the group algebra $FG$ is semi-simple by Maschke's theorem. Now $FG$ is an $FG$-module, so if it had a faithful irreducible $FG$-submodule then surely it  isn't (irreducible)?

Comment: @jackwo If you follow to the semisimple part, I am saying that a semisimple ring has a faithful irreducible module (meaning simple module) iff it is a simple ring. I'm basing this off of my knowledge of rings with faithful simple right modules (they are called [right primitive rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_ring). A semisimple, right primitive ring is necessarily simple. But a group algebra $FG$ is simple iff $|G|=1$.

Comment: So there isn't an irreducible faithful FG-module?

Comment: @jackwo If "irreducible" is used in the sense "simple," then for any field $F$ and finite group $G$, $FG$ will not have a faithful simple module unless $|G|=1$.

Comment: We've defined an irreducible $FG$-module $V$, to be an $FG$-module where the only $FG$-submodules are $V$ and $\{0\}$.

Comment: I think our logic may be getting mixed up, we are looking for a faithful irreducible $FG$-module. Where an $FG$-module, $V$ is a vector space over $F$ with a multiplication $vg$ for $v\in V$, $g \in G$ satisfying specific axioms.

Comment: @jackwo 1) Great, then we're on the same page for "irreducible."  2) I think we're also on the same page for $FG$ modules. The axioms you list for $FG$ (your sense of) modules ought to make $V$ a module over the group ring $FG$ (my sense), and conversely any module over the ring $FG$ (my sense) is a module in your sense: you just focus on the action by the elements of $G$ and ignore other elements of $FG$.

Comment: For clarity the axioms are 1) $vg \in V$ , 2) $v(gh)=(vg)h$ , 3)$v.1=v$ , 4)$(\lambda v)g=\lambda(vg)$ , 5)$(u+v)g=ug+vg$ where $u,v \in V$, $g,h \in V$ and $\lambda \in F$

Comment: @jackwo What evidence do you have that the problem was correctly written? For example, is it coming out of some textbook that we can both look at online?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's on a problem sheet and is worded exactly the same as I have stated.

Comment: @jackwo I can't say anything else. Excepting the case where we somehow misunderstood the question, the solution I've given is the best I can do. Maybe you should ask the author if there's a typo, and/or maybe bring up the ideas I'm mentioning.

Comment: OK so I think I've finally managed to get somewhere now! I've proved that the centre $Z(G)=\mathbb{Z}_{r}$ and deduced that $\mathbb{Z}_{r}$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $G$. By a lemma I have from lectures, there exists an irreducible $FG$-module $V$ and by Clifford's Theorem, $V=U_{1}\oplus...\oplus U_{k}$, where the $U_{i}$ are irreducible $FM$-modules ($M:=\mathbb{Z}_{r}^{2}$). However now I'm now stuck! Apparently, I have to prove that $k=r$ and $dim(U_{i})=1$, but I'm not sure how to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!.